# Scraping data from table with unique IDs

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape from [this](https://us.soccerway.com/teams/england/tottenham-hotspur-football-club/675/matches/) website. My objective is to collect the most recent 10 results (win/loss/draw) of ANY team, I am just using this specific team as an example. The source for an individual row is:

```
<tr class="odd      match no-date-repetition" data-timestamp="1515864600" id="page_team_1_block_team_matches_3_match-2463021" data-competition="8">
        <td class="day no-repetition">Sat</td>


        <td class="full-date" nowrap="nowrap">13/01/18</td>
        <td class="competition"><a href="/national/england/premier-league/20172018/regular-season/r41547/" title="Premier League">PRL</a></td>

          <td class="team team-a ">
              <a href="/teams/england/tottenham-hotspur-football-club/675/" title="Tottenham Hotspur">
                Tottenham Hotspur
              </a>
          </td>

        <td class="score-time score">
          <a href="/matches/2018/01/13/england/premier-league/tottenham-hotspur-football-club/everton-football-club/2463021/" class="result-win">

            4 - 0

          </a>
        </td>
          <td class="team team-b ">
            <a href="/teams/england/everton-football-club/674/" title="Everton">
              Everton
            </a>
          </td>
        <td class="events-button button first-occur">
            <a href="/matches/2018/01/13/england/premier-league/tottenham-hotspur-football-club/everton-football-club/2463021/#events" title="View events" class="events-button-button ">View events</a>
        </td>

          <td class="info-button button">

              <a href="/matches/2018/01/13/england/premier-league/tottenham-hotspur-football-club/everton-football-club/2463021/" title="More info">More info</a>



          </td>




      </tr>
```

You can see in the `<td class="score-time score"`, the result is stored.
My knowledge of Python and web crawling is pretty limited, so my current code is:

```
res2 = requests.get(soccerwayURL)
soup2 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res2.text, 'html.parser')
elems2 = soup2.select('#page_team_1_block_team_matches_3_match-2463021 > td.score-time.score')
print(elems2[0].text.strip())
```

This prints out '4-0'. That is good, but the issue arises when I try to access a different row. The 7-digit number (2463021 in the example above) is unique to that row. That means that if I want to get the score from a different row, I would have to find that unique 7-digit number and place it in the CSS selector `'#page_team_1_block_team_matches_3_match-******* > td.score-time.score'` where the asterisks are the unique number.

The online course I took only showed how to reference things by the CSS Selector, so I am  unsure how I can go about retrieving the scores without manually taking the CSS Selector for each row.

Within the `<td class="score-time score">` class, there is another class that reads `class="result-win">`. Ideally I would like to be able to pull just that `"result-win"` because I am not looking for the score of the game, I am only looking for the outcome of win, loss, or draw.

I hope this post is clear. My knowledge is limited so I apologize if my vocabulary isn't exactly spot on with some of the technical terms.

My objective statement is: "Retrieve the most recent 10 results (win, loss, draw) from any team on the Soccerway website."

Comment: Try the [`*=`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp) selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib3

#Had some security issues. Had to disable it. Be careful!
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

#Need to disable verifying ssl.Be careful!
r = requests.get('https://us.soccerway.com/teams/england/tottenham-hotspur-football-club/675/matches/',verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

matches = soup.find('table',{'class':'matches'}).find('tbody')

i = 0
for row in matches.find_all('tr'):
    #For first ten result
    if i == 10:
        break
    else:
        i +=1

    data = row.find_all('td')
    home_team = data[3].text.strip()
    match_result = data[4].text.strip()
    match_result_class = data[4].find('a').attrs['class'][0]
    away_team = data[5].text.strip()

    output = str.format('Home team : {0}, Away team : {1}, Match Result Class :{2}',home_team,away_team,match_result_class)
    print(output)
```

And the output is

```
Home team : Newcastle United, Away team : Tottenham Hotspur, Match Result Class :result-win
Home team : Tottenham Hotspur, Away team : Chelsea, Match Result Class :result-loss
Home team : Tottenham Hotspur, Away team : Burnley, Match Result Class :result-draw
Home team : Everton, Away team : Tottenham Hotspur, Match Result Class :result-win
Home team : Tottenham Hotspur, Away team : Borussia Dortmund, Match Result Class :result-win
Home team : Tottenham Hotspur, Away team : Swansea City, Match Result Class :result-draw
Home team : Tottenham Hotspur, Away team : Barnsley, Match Result Class :result-win
Home team : West Ham United, Away team : Tottenham Hotspur, Match Result Class :result-win
Home team : APOEL, Away team : Tottenham Hotspur, Match Result Class :result-win
Home team : Huddersfield Town, Away team : Tottenham Hotspur, Match Result Class :result-win
```

Comment: This is AMAZING! I cannot thank you enough. Not only did this solve my problem, but I learned a lot about how to navigate BS4 objects as well. I altered the code to now give me the most recent 15 games (most recent ones are at the bottom unfortunately, not the top), and everything works awesome now. I'm working with some debugging now where if a game is cancelled, it throws an error, so I'm making some exceptions for that. Anyways, thank you so much once again. This gave me a breakthrough in my project and gave me so much motivation to continue. Cheers and have a great one :)